# Google in-app billing service disconnected error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-services, android-billing

I am using an Android 4.2 Set top box and installed an app I developed using the In-app billing feature.
The moment the pop up of the in app billing comes I get an error :

> service disconnected. please login to the google service

The app works fine on my android phone and tablet. I am connected to google play so I don't see why this is happening.